# Intersection Observer cannot increase only the top rootMargin

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm trying to increase only the top value of the [rootMargin](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#dom-intersectionobserverinit-rootmargin) by 50px. The code I'm using for the option is `rootMargin: '50px 0px 0px 0px'`. And that isn't working.

Although using `rootMargin: '50px 0px'` can work for my case, I have no desire to increase the bottom value.

The full test code is listed below. I did not create a demo on jsFiddle because jsFiddle wraps the result in an iframe, which would be the [`root`](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#dom-intersectionobserver-root). I cannot set that iframe as the root on jsFiddle so the demo would not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>rootMargin test</title>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#full-height {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
#observee {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="full-height"></div>
<p id="observee">I'm being observed.</p>

<script>
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    function(entries) {
        entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                console.log('Intersected.');
            }
        });
    },
    {
        rootMargin: '50px 0px 0px 0px'
    }
);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#observee'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue and can't explain why. `rootMargin` is ignored when I set 4 values, but it works when I set only 2 values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is an older question, I think the following may help users with similar issues.

1. You can run the demo in JSFiddle - just change the root you want to use as the trigger. See the demo below to highlight this.
2. I think you may be confusing the [rootMargin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin) properties. From you question, it sounds like you want the observed element to trigger 50px **before** it comes into view. If that is the case, then you want to increase the root **bottom** margin: `0px 0px 50px 0px` if you want to trigger the element only when it reaches 50px inside the root, then use: `0px 0px -50px 0px`. You can leave off the last value like: `0px 0px 50px` which would be `top left/right bottom`

See the demo below:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otvbzeL9/2/)